# (PHP) Why is my DateTime object property force-cast to a string, but only when accessed from a different class?

Tags: php, datetime, casting

This is not making any sense to me—perhaps it makes sense to someone else here.

I have a class called `Event` which represents, well, an event. It has three properties: an `id`, a `description`, and a `time`. The `time` property is itself an object of type `DateTime`.

A third class, `Member`, has a property called `Events`, which is populated with an array of `Event` objects. A simple `var_dump` of a `Member` object thus looks like this, leaving out some more properties that aren’t relevant here:

```
object(Member)#5 (32) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  string(3) "127"
  ["events":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Event)#13 (4) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["description":protected]=>
      string(10) "Some text here"
      ["time":protected]=>
      object(DateTime)#14 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(17) "Europe/London"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Within the `Member` class, there is a function to list all events in tabular form, `formatEventsAsTable()` which, in a nutshell does this:

```
public function formatEvents() {
    $return = <<<EOT
        <table>
            <tbody>
EOT;

    foreach ($this->events as $event) {
        $date = $event->time->format('j/n Y');
        $return .= <<<EOT
                <tr>
                    <td>$date</td>
                    <td>$event->text</td>
                </tr>
EOT;
    }

    $return .= <<<EOT
            </tbody>
        </table>
EOT;

    return $return;
}
```

As far as I can tell, this should work: in the loop, `$event` is an `Event` object (verifiable by `var_dump`ing it during the loop) with a property `time` that is a `DateTime` object and should thus have the [`format`](http://php.net/DateTime.format) function. **But it doesn’t work.**

For some reason, the `DateTime` object gets force-cast to a string, and I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on string in /path/to/file/class.Member.php:116

This is most unexpected to me: `var_dump $event` shows the property `time` to be a DateTime object. But `var_dump $event->time` yields:

```
string(10) "2010-01-01"
```

Even more bizarrely: if instead I put the actual code in the `foreach` loop inside the `Event` class, adding a function `Event::formatAsTableRow()` that calls `$this->time->format('j/n Y')`, and then simply call that function in the `foreach` loop in `Member::formatEventsAsTable()`… **then it works just fine**.

#### So why can I access a DateTime object as such from within the class where it’s a property, but not from a function in a different class? Why does it get force-cast (?) to a string there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that I’m an idiot.

Both the `Member` and `Event` classes extend a base class, and I had apparently at some point defined a magic `__toString()` method in that class, in which I specifically check for `DateTime` objects and output them exactly as I saw them here, as `'Y-m-d'` strings.

I’m still puzzled as to why `var_dump`ing the object would invoke its `__toString()` method, though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the problem here is that you are trying to access protected class member from outside its access scope.

I don't know, though, why you are getting this particular error, while you should get `Cannot access protected property of Event::time` kind of error. Even more, I've made up some code similar to yours and I get correct error (php 5.4.45). I'd like to know version of PHP you are using.

Comment: Oh, of course! What a brainfart. I'm on 7.0.0 (I think); I suppose this could be a bug (if it is that) that's been introduced in PHP7. If it had told me I was trying to access a protected member, I would never have been this puzzled. I suppose perhaps `DateTime` has had a `__get()` magic function implemented in PHP7.

Comment: Huh. Tried that on different branches of 7.0.0, still couldn't reproduce the same effect. My best guess is that there's a bit more code to it than you shared and it somehow affects resulting error. Did change of visibility of this variable help, though?

Comment: It's half past one in the morning here, so I just turned off the computer. Will test tomorrow if visibility changes fix it. Just realised, though: `var_dump` does access protected properties, so it can't only be visibility, since `var_dump`ing the `DateTime` object itself also shows it as a string. `var_dump ($event)` = `$event->time` is a DateTime object, protected members are dumpable; `var_dump ($event->time)` = `$event->time` is a string.

Comment: It might have something to do with new error handling techniques introduced in php7. Are you catching exceptions somewhere there in your code by any chance? The thing is, since 7.0.0 such fatal errors aren't reported via standard mechanism, instead it's thrown as Error object, which, as far as documentation states, has __toString() method declared, which might produce same effect as yours if exceptions aren't handled correctly. I still believe that devil lurks somewhere in the code you thought wasn't related to the problem

Comment: Yup, changing visibility to `public` fixed it—it then `var_dump`s to a `DateTime` object.

Comment: Also, I just found the underlying culprit—and it’s entirely my own fault (of course)! Both the `Member` and `Event` classes extend a base class, and in that base class, I’ve defined my own `__toString()` method, _which specifically checks for `DateTime` objects and outputs them as `Y-m-d`_. So much duh here right now! :-$